# Stopping glUseProgram()

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, textures, shader

I'm using an opengl shader on a texture. Once the texture is done shading I want to stop the glUseProgram() function.

Presently the shader is going overtop of everything, including rectf() functions that I need to not be shaded.

I tried glUseProgram(0) but that didn't work.

related question: [Java Opengl: Discarding Texture Background with Shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617503/java-opengl-discarding-texture-background-with-shaders)

Here is the relevant code.

```
        glPushMatrix();
        dirPosd = i.torso.getPosition().mul(30);
        glTranslatef(dirPosd.x, dirPosd.y, 0);
        glRotated(Math.toDegrees(i.torso.getAngle()), 0, 0, 1);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        skel_torso.bind();
        sizer = 40;
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex2f( i.torso.getPosition().x - sizer-5, i.torso.getPosition().y - sizer-5);     //NW
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f( i.torso.getPosition().x + sizer-5, i.torso.getPosition().y - sizer-5);   //NE
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f( i.torso.getPosition().x + sizer-5, i.torso.getPosition().y + sizer-5); //SE
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f( i.torso.getPosition().x - sizer-5, i.torso.getPosition().y + sizer-5);   //SW
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        glUseProgram(0); //Note here

        glPushMatrix();

        Vec2 shoulderPosL = i.shouldL.getPosition().mul(30);
        glTranslatef(shoulderPosL.x, shoulderPosL.y, 0);
        glRotated(Math.toDegrees(i.shouldL.getAngle()), 0, 0, 1);

        glColor3f(1,1,0);
        glRectf(-i.shoulderSize[0] * 30, -i.shoulderSize[1] * 30, i.shoulderSize[0] * 30, i.shoulderSize[1] * 30);

        glPopMatrix();`
```

I've added a glUseProgram(0) statement, but when I added that the shader doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to a different shader, doing what you want for the other stuff rendering. Shaders are not something "wrapped" over something you render. Shaders are what make rendering work. If you disable the shaders, and your OpenGL context is not a compatibility profile no default fallback (to fixed function pipeline behavior) is provided and nothing renders. OTOH you're using the fixed function pipeline, but for that to work you have to parametize it properly (enable texture targets, modulation modes, colors and so on). It's generally easier to simply switch shaders instead of juggle with the FF pipeline state.

Comment: What would that look like in terms of code? Like glUseProgram(otherShader)? This function with 0 as a parameter is presumably 'null'. Do I have to write another frag/vertex shader source that is simply blank and bind it, etc?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer: A blank shader is invalid and would produce no output. **Shaders are not image filters!** Shaders are what make things actually draw. So you have to write another shader that will produce exactly the kind of output you need for the rest of the geometry. – Or you could start juggling the fixed function pipeline state, which would be, on average some 20 calls just to set things up properly. Writing an appropriate shader and just calling `glUseShader(other_shader)` is usually less effort.

Comment: I created another shaderProgram but again, it's either everything is shaded or nothing, no matter what order I call each useProgram(). I'm trying to draw an texture, shade on it (discard white background) then draw a reftf() over top of the texture. Is this even possible?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer: The second iteration of the same geometry will normally not pass, as the depth test will discard in coming fragments, that are occluded with preexisting geometry. What is it exactly you're trying to do. I get the impression you want to do something, that could easily be done within a single shader.

Comment: I'm using a shader to discard the white background in an image I'm blitting to the screen. When I activate the shader, though, it shades over my Rectf(). I need the Rect() blitted on top of the image.

Comment: I basically need some things shaded and not others and this useProgram() function either applies it to everything or nothing.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer: Yes. That's how it works. I'll repeat: Shaders are not some kind of selective filter. With modern OpenGL you always need some kind of shader being active so that something appears. Without a shader nothing will draw. Unless you're using fixed function OpenGL. In your code you have a weird mix of legacy OpenGL and modern OpenGL code. You should fix that. You can make it work, but IMHO it's not worthwhile.